# ASP.NET Creating multi-level JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to create multi-level JSON object as a result of my ASP.NET web service. I am using Fiddler to see what is the web service returning. I also have web service on some other web site, which is returning what I want. Here are the examples:

This is what it should look like:

[image: This is what it should look like:]
This is how it looks for me now:

[image: This is what it should look like:]
I am using JavaScriptSerializer to make JSON object from ASP.NET List. Can anyone please tell me, how can I achieve this good looking structure instead of mine flat structure? I will be using this JSON object with jQuery then.

My code:

```
List<ResultItem> results = new List<ResultItem> { };
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                results.Add(new ResultItem { T = ValidationHelper.GetString(row[4], ""), A = "Adresa", E = "0 akci" });
            }

            resultCategories.Add(new ResultCategory { T = "Mesta", I = results });

            json = resultCategories.ToJSON();
```

JSON Helper

```
public static class JSONHelper
{
    public static string ToJSON(this object obj)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(obj);
    }

    public static string ToJSON(this object obj, int recursionDepth)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.RecursionLimit = recursionDepth;
        return serializer.Serialize(obj);
    }
}
```

Classes:

```
public class ResultCategory
{
    public string T { get; set; }// Title
    public List<ResultItem> I { get; set; }
}

public class ResultItem
{
    public string T { get; set; }// Title
    public string A { get; set; }// Address
    public string E { get; set; }// Events number
}
```

Comment: What is the code that generates the second block of JSON?

Comment: I added it to the bottom of my question. Hope this part of a code is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will be facing the same problem as I did. Answer is in the returning type of a web service. If you are returning string and response format is set to Json, .NET automatically serializes your string. So after first serialization, .NET did another and it simply escaped all my ". So that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the raw json from Fiddler, and paste it into this site: http://json2csharp.com/.  It will create the C# classes you need in order to serialize back to the desired JSON format.

Comment: @JacobH - We need to keep the conversation to English, so anyone can join.  Here's a rough translation of his comment: I tried that and basically the structure I have too. I do not need it completely identical. The problem is rather that way then I create JSON format. In the first case, the raw JSON data without escaping quotes. For me, the quotes are escaped, it's probably the problem.